# If Else Condition at Trigger in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I have two tables.They are

```
CARD(cardid, credit, usertype,charge)
```

and

```
PAYMENTDEVICE(paydevid, paydevip,paydevdate, paydevtime, chargedcardid, mealtype).
```

Mealtype can be 'guest' or 'standard'. I want to update credit that is in card table, when a new row is inserted in paymentdevice. Charge depends on usertype. But if meal type is guest, everyone has to pay 5$ . I try to use following code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TRG_PAYMONEY" 
AFTER INSERT
ON PAYMENTDEVICE FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
UPDATE CARD
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID
SET CREDIT = 
(CASE MEALTYPE

WHEN "STANDARD" THEN CREDIT - CHARGE
WHEN "GUEST" THEN CREDIT - 5
END);
END;
```

But i get this error : 
`PL/SQL: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword, PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow this syntax for update,

```
update table_name set field1='value' where field2='value'
```

(ie)

```
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = 
(CASE MEALTYPE
WHEN "STANDARD" THEN CREDIT - CHARGE
WHEN "GUEST" THEN CREDIT - 5
END)
 WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
```

For more, how `'update'` statement works refer to this doc,

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm

For your second error try this,

```
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = 
(CASE 
WHEN MEALTYPE="STANDARD" THEN CREDIT - CHARGE
WHEN MEALTYPE="GUEST" THEN CREDIT - 5
END MEALTYPE) 
 WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
```

Something like this,

```
update card c
set c.credit=(select case when p.mealtype='STANDARD' then c.credit-c.charge
                 when p.mealtype='GUEST' then c.credit-5
            end credit from PAYMENTDEVICE p
           where c.cardid=p.chargedcardid)
```

[fiddle_demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/309cd/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement should be (`WHERE` should be after `SET`)

```
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = 
(CASE MEALTYPE

WHEN "STANDARD" THEN CREDIT - CHARGE
WHEN "GUEST" THEN CREDIT - 5
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID
```

Answer (score 0):

please run this code..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PAYMONEY1
AFTER INSERT ON PAYMENTDEVICE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE CARD c
SET c.credit=(select case when p.mealtype='STANDARD' then c.credit-c.charge
                 when p.mealtype='GUEST' then c.credit-5
            end result from PAYMENTDEVICE p,card c
           where c.cardid=p.chargedcardid)
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
END;
```

Comment: It still gives that error ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.PAYMENTDEVICE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TRG_PAYMONEY1", line 2 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TRG_PAYMONEY1'

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little research and thanks to  [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) we solved our problem with this implementation :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TRG_PAYMONEY" 
AFTER INSERT
ON PAYMENTDEVICE FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
IF :NEW.MEALTYPE='GUEST' THEN
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = CREDIT - 5
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
ELSE
UPDATE CARD
SET CREDIT = CREDIT - CHARGE
WHERE CARDID = :NEW.CHARGEDCARDID;
END IF;
END;
```

And thank you for your help & advices.